# landscape mode not working for ipad converted app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am making my application universal for iPad.  Everything works great for iphone but when I run it in the ipad simulator in landscape mode the navigation bar is missing from my uinavigation view and every view is shifted up by about 30 pixels.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: paste some samples of ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: For other views everything is fine.  So I rotate 3 times and it all works.  Then I rotate back and it is messes up again offset up.  It is as though it gets calculated wrong on startup and I cannot get it to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Print the navigation bar frame and also check the orientation methods.